# Why does fit type not accept my convoluted function as input? (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

The ultimate goal is to fit a costum equation to experimental data by (Z = f(X,Y)). The general equation is given by:

```
Rw = conv2([zeros(4095,11);((1/(3*redmu+mu_a))^(-3/2)).*(X).^(-5/2).*...
        exp(-mu_a*2.*(X)).*exp(-(Y.^2)./(4/(3*redmu+mu_a)*2.*X))],IRF,'valid');
```

Where mu_a and redmu are the fitting parameters.

The generalized piece of code I wrote can be seen below:

```
IRF = rand(4096,1);
X = (1:4096)';
Y = 1:11;
ft_notworking = fittype(@(mu_a,redmu,X,Y) conv2([zeros(4095,11);((1/(3*redmu+mu_a))^(-3/2)).*(X).^(-5/2).*...
        exp(-mu_a*2.*(X)).*exp(-(Y.^2)./(4/(3*redmu+mu_a)*2.*X))],IRF,'valid'),'independent',{'X','Y'},'coefficient',{'mu_a','redmu'});
```

It gives an error: "Dimensions of arrays being concatenated
are not consistent.". That is strange as I use the `zeros(4095,11)` and `shape = 'valid'` for the conv2 function to make sure the shape of Rw = 4096x11. Just as the input parameters `X` and `Y` are spanning. If I get rid of the convolution (as shown below) I don't get any error. This makes me suspect that the convolution and fittype function don't work together very well.

```
ft = fittype(@(mu_a,redmu,x,y) (((1/(3*redmu+mu_a))^(-3/2)).*x.^(-5/2).*...
        exp(-mu_a*2.*(x)).*exp(-(y.^2)./(4/(3*redmu+mu_a)*2.*x))),...
'independent',{'x','y'},'coefficient',{'mu_a','redmu'})
```

What I don't get is this: Both Rw and the unconvoluted equation have the same shape `4096x11`, but for Rw we get an error and for the other we don't.

Additionally I tried to write a function that calculates Rw (the convoluted function) in the desired dimensions 4096x11 and named it test.m. I call the function in the fittype function as:

```
ft = fittype('test( tw, rw, mu_a,redmu)','independent',{'tw','rw'},'coefficient',{'mu_a','redmu'});
```

I get the same error as before. So it looks like the convolution messes it up. That is unfortunate as I need the convolution. Is anyone able to help me with this problem?

Best regards

P.S Here is a script you could use to test stuff

```
   redmu = 10;
   mu_a = 0;

   IRF = rand(4096,1);
   X = (1:4096)';
   Y = 1:11;

   Rw = conv2([zeros(4095,11);((1/(3*redmu+mu_a))^(-3/2)).*(X).^(-5/2).*...
        exp(-mu_a*2.*(X)).*exp(-(Y.^2)./(4/(3*redmu+mu_a)*2.*X))],IRF,'valid');   

   ft_notworking = fittype(@(mu_a,redmu,X,Y) conv2([zeros(4095,11);((1/(3*redmu+mu_a))^(-3/2)).*(X).^(-5/2).*...
        exp(-mu_a*2.*(X)).*exp(-(Y.^2)./(4/(3*redmu+mu_a)*2.*X))],IRF,'valid'),'independent',{'X','Y'},'coefficient',{'mu_a','redmu'});
            
   ft_working = fittype(@(mu_a,redmu,X,Y) (((1/(3*redmu+mu_a))^(-3/2)).*(X).^(-5/2).*...
        exp(-mu_a*2.*(X)).*exp(-(Y.^2)./(4/(3*redmu+mu_a)*2.*X))),'independent',{'X','Y'},'coefficient',{'mu_a','redmu'});
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is interested: the problem is that the `fittype` function tries the function with arbitrary time and radius values. The convolution only works for a specified grid. So if you add the line:

```
Rw = interp2(XX,YY,new,tw,rw);
```

Where `XX` and `YY` is the meshgrid spanned by `X` and `Y`. Now the input will be drawn towards a gridpoint and won't end up in an "undefined" place in the code world.

This works better with the function file `fittype`, compared to the anonymous function definition. The final code looks like:

Function 1: `Rw = nonconv(t,r,mu_a,redmu)`

```
Rw = (((1/(3*redmu+mu_a))^(-3/2)).*(t).^(-5/2).*...
            exp(-mu_a*2.*(t)).*exp(-(r.^2)./(4/(3*redmu+mu_a)*2.*t)));
```

Function 2: `Rw = yesconv(t,r,mu_a,redmu,IRF)`

```
X = (1:4096); %time
Y = 1:11; %r
[XX,YY]=meshgrid(X,Y);

new = conv2(nonconv(X,Y,mu_a,redmu),IRF); 
new = transpose(new(1:4096,:));
new= new./max(new(:));
Rw = interp2(XX,YY,new,t,r);
```

And the fittype becomes:

```
ft = fittype('yesconv(t, r, mu_a, redmu , IRF)','independent',{'t','r'},'coefficient',{'mu_a','redmu'}, 'problem','IRF')
```